# Java program not compiling IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, compilation, stack-trace

I'm trying to compile my java project in Intellij IDEA, however upon click `Build` it throws the following error:

```
2:21:43 PM: Executing external tasks ':classes :testClasses'...
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I don't have any visible errors in code that should have been pointed out by lint if there existed any errors.

I have tried putting `--stacktrace` command in `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler` & `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Gradle-Android Compiler  -> Command line Options`

But I still get the same error upon building the code without a stacktrace.

What should I do to fix it?

Build Configuration:

[image]

[image]

***IDE version: IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4 Community Edition.***

Comment: what is your current build configuration and what type of project are you trying to build? do share the intelliJ/java/gradle version as well.

Comment: You also tried with --info and --debug parameter?

Comment: @nullpointer I have added a screenshot of my build configuration

Comment: What happens if you [disable this option](http://i.imgur.com/jIB5muQ.png)?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself. Coming from Android Studio that handles everything for you to IntelliJ has a relative good amount of learning curve.

My mistake was I didn't select `Use auto-import` When I was creating the java project. As a result, IntelliJ idea didn't download and integrate Gradle binaries in the project.

I created a new project with the mentioned option selected and now I can run `gradlew` commands from terminal.